# Compare 2 Arrays of Objects and Remove Duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have 2 arrays of objects in JavaScript and would like to compare and merge the contents and sort the results by id. Specifically, the resulting sorted array should contain all objects from the 1st array, plus all objects from the 2nd array that have an id that's not in the 1st.

The following code seems to work (minus the sorting). But there must be a better, more succinct way to do this, particularly with features from ES6. I assume using a Set is the way to go, but not sure exactly how to implement.

```js
    var cars1 = [
        {id: 2, make: "Honda", model: "Civic", year: 2001},
        {id: 1, make: "Ford",  model: "F150",  year: 2002},
        {id: 3, make: "Chevy", model: "Tahoe", year: 2003},
    ];
    
    var cars2 = [
        {id: 3, make: "Kia",    model: "Optima",  year: 2001},
        {id: 4, make: "Nissan", model: "Sentra",  year: 1982},
        {id: 2, make: "Toyota", model: "Corolla", year: 1980},
    ];
    
    // Resulting cars1 contains all cars from cars1 plus unique cars from cars2
    cars1 = removeDuplicates(cars2);
    console.log(cars1);
    
    function removeDuplicates(cars2){
        for (entry in cars2) {
            var keep = true;
    
            for (c in cars1) {
                if (cars1[c].id === cars2[entry].id) {
                    keep = false;
                }
            }
    
            if (keep) {
                cars1.push({
                    id:cars2[entry].id,
                    make:cars2[entry].make,
                    model:cars2[entry].model,
                    year:cars2[entry].year
                })
            }
        }
        return cars1;
    }
```

Comment: This question should be posted in [Code Review | StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One option with `O(N)` complexity would be to make a `Set` of the `id`s in `cars1`, then spread `cars1` and a filtered `cars2` into the ouput array, with the filter testing whether the `id` in the car being iterated over in `cars2` is included in the Set:

```js
var cars1 = [
    {id: 2, make: "Honda", model: "Civic", year: 2001},
    {id: 1, make: "Ford",  model: "F150",  year: 2002},
    {id: 3, make: "Chevy", model: "Tahoe", year: 2003},
];

var cars2 = [
    {id: 3, make: "Kia",    model: "Optima",  year: 2001},
    {id: 4, make: "Nissan", model: "Sentra",  year: 1982},
    {id: 2, make: "Toyota", model: "Corolla", year: 1980},
];
const cars1IDs = new Set(cars1.map(({ id }) => id));
const combined = [
  ...cars1,
  ...cars2.filter(({ id }) => !cars1IDs.has(id))
];
console.log(combined);
```

To `sort` as well:

```
combined.sort(({ id: aId }, {id: bId }) => aId - bId);
```

```js
var cars1 = [
    {id: 2, make: "Honda", model: "Civic", year: 2001},
    {id: 1, make: "Ford",  model: "F150",  year: 2002},
    {id: 3, make: "Chevy", model: "Tahoe", year: 2003},
];

var cars2 = [
    {id: 3, make: "Kia",    model: "Optima",  year: 2001},
    {id: 4, make: "Nissan", model: "Sentra",  year: 1982},
    {id: 2, make: "Toyota", model: "Corolla", year: 1980},
];
const cars1IDs = new Set(cars1.map(({ id }) => id));
const combined = [
  ...cars1,
  ...cars2.filter(({ id }) => !cars1IDs.has(id))
];
combined.sort(({ id: aId }, {id: bId }) => aId - bId);
console.log(combined);
```

Comment: The `Set()` object approach is perfect for this. +1

Comment: Just add this `sort()` method in the last line like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/Ly84ekuz/5/) to make sure the new array is sorted too : `combined.sort((a,b) => (a.id > b.id) ? 1 : ((b.id > a.id) ? -1 : 0));`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance It works well, but when i delete an item from DB remotely it's should be deleted from UI but the deleted item stuck in the UI :\  BUT when I add new item remotely it's added very well!

Comment: @OliverD There's no DB or remote connections in this question nor in my answer. If you have a new question, press the Ask Question button

Answer (score 2):

You could use `concat`, `filter` and `map`.

```js
var cars1 = [ {id: 2, make: "Honda", model: "Civic", year: 2001}, {id: 1, make: "Ford", model: "F150", year: 2002}, {id: 3, make: "Chevy", model: "Tahoe", year: 2003}, ];

var cars2 = [ {id: 3, make: "Kia", model: "Optima", year: 2001}, {id: 4, make: "Nissan", model: "Sentra", year: 1982}, {id: 2, make: "Toyota", model: "Corolla", year: 1980}, ];

// Resulting cars1 contains all cars from cars1 plus unique cars from cars2
let ids = cars1.map(c => c.id);
cars1 = cars1.concat(cars2.filter(({id}) => !ids.includes(id)))
console.log(cars1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Merge two arrays, put each array element in a map with their `ids` and then create array from the map values.

```js
var cars1 = [
    {id: 2, make: "Honda", model: "Civic", year: 2001},
    {id: 1, make: "Ford",  model: "F150",  year: 2002},
    {id: 3, make: "Chevy", model: "Tahoe", year: 2003},
];

var cars2 = [
    {id: 3, make: "Kia",    model: "Optima",  year: 2001},
    {id: 4, make: "Nissan", model: "Sentra",  year: 1982},
    {id: 2, make: "Toyota", model: "Corolla", year: 1980},
];

cars = cars1.concat(cars2);
let foo = new Map();
for(const c of cars){
  foo.set(c.id, c);
}
let final = [...foo.values()]
console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and take the item of them map first or the actual car.

```js
var cars1 = [{ id: 2, make: "Honda", model: "Civic", year: 2001 }, { id: 1, make: "Ford",  model: "F150",  year: 2002 }, { id: 3, make: "Chevy", model: "Tahoe", year: 2003 }],
    cars2 = [{ id: 3, make: "Kia",    model: "Optima",  year: 2001 }, { id: 4, make: "Nissan", model: "Sentra",  year: 1982 }, { id: 2, make: "Toyota", model: "Corolla", year: 1980 }],
    result = Array
        .from(
            [...cars1, ...cars2]
                .reduce((m, c) => m.set(c.id, m.get(c.id) || c), new Map)
                .values()
        )
        .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.values()` alongwith `.concat()` and `.reduce()`:

```js
let cars1 = [
    {id: 2, make: "Honda", model: "Civic", year: 2001},
    {id: 1, make: "Ford",  model: "F150",  year: 2002},
    {id: 3, make: "Chevy", model: "Tahoe", year: 2003},
];

let cars2 = [
    {id: 3, make: "Kia",    model: "Optima",  year: 2001},
    {id: 4, make: "Nissan", model: "Sentra",  year: 1982},
    {id: 2, make: "Toyota", model: "Corolla", year: 1980},
];

let merge = (arr1, arr2) => Object.values(
    arr1.concat(arr2).reduce((r, c) => (r[c.id] = r[c.id] || c, r), {})
).sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

console.log(merge(cars1, cars2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the id's should be unique, this should work:

```
var union = (arr1, arr2) => 
{
    var result = arr1.slice(0);
    arr2.forEach((el) => 
    { 
        if (getIndexByAttribute(arr1, 'id', el.id) < 0)
            result .push(el); 
    });
    return result;
};

var getIndexByAttribute = (array, attr, value) => {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        if(array[i][attr] === value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

But with your current examples `cars1` and `cars2`, you might need object camparison. Please see [Object comparison in JavaScript [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript/6713782#6713782)

Answer (score 1):

One approach can be using `concat()` with the elements of `cars2` whose ids are not already on `cars1`, this can be checked using `find()`. And finally `sort()` the resulting array:

```js
var cars1 = [
    {id: 2, make: "Honda", model: "Civic", year: 2001},
    {id: 1, make: "Ford",  model: "F150",  year: 2002},
    {id: 3, make: "Chevy", model: "Tahoe", year: 2003},
];
    
var cars2 = [
    {id: 3, make: "Kia",    model: "Optima",  year: 2001},
    {id: 4, make: "Nissan", model: "Sentra",  year: 1982},
    {id: 2, make: "Toyota", model: "Corolla", year: 1980},
];

let res = cars1
    .concat(cars2.filter(({id}) => !cars1.find(x => x.id === id)))
    .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```