# Unable to filter an array of object based on another array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two array of objects containing key-value pairs of `dateTime` string and `count`. In `arr`, I have two objects which have same `dateTime` values with two of `brr's` object's `dateTime` values. I just want to filter out `arr's` non-equal objects in an array.

What I mean to say is, if my `arr` is this:

```
const arr = [
    { dateTime: '2021-08-14 02:00:00', count: 1 },
    { dateTime: '2021-08-15 04:00:00', count: 1 },
    { dateTime: '2021-08-16 10:00:00', count: 1 },
    { dateTime: '2021-08-16 19:00:00', count: 1 },
    { dateTime: '2021-08-17 05:00:00', count: 1 }
];
```

and `brr` is this:

```
const brr = [
    { dateTime: '2021-08-16 19:00:00', count: 1 },
    { dateTime: '2021-08-17 05:00:00', count: 1 }
];
```

I am trying to get an array like this:

```
[
    { dateTime: '2021-08-14 02:00:00', count: 1 },
    { dateTime: '2021-08-15 04:00:00', count: 1 },
    { dateTime: '2021-08-16 10:00:00', count: 1 }
];
```

Failing to do so with this:

```js
const arr = [
    { dateTime: '2021-08-14 02:00:00', count: 1 },
    { dateTime: '2021-08-15 04:00:00', count: 1 },
    { dateTime: '2021-08-16 10:00:00', count: 1 },
    { dateTime: '2021-08-16 19:00:00', count: 1 },
    { dateTime: '2021-08-17 05:00:00', count: 1 }
];

const brr = [
    { dateTime: '2021-08-16 19:00:00', count: 1 },
    { dateTime: '2021-08-17 05:00:00', count: 1 }
];

const newArr = [];

for( let item of brr ) { 

   const filtered = arr.filter( el => {
        return el.dateTime !== item.dateTime;  
   });
   
   newArr.push( filtered );
  
};

console.log( newArr );
```

I am getting some gibberish in the console. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: see if this helps you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142112/compare-2-arrays-of-objects-and-remove-duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a set of unwanted `dateTime` values and filter the array.

```js
const
    array = [{ dateTime: '2021-08-14 02:00:00', count: 1 }, { dateTime: '2021-08-15 04:00:00', count: 1 }, { dateTime: '2021-08-16 10:00:00', count: 1 }, { dateTime: '2021-08-16 19:00:00', count: 1 }, { dateTime: '2021-08-17 05:00:00', count: 1 }],
    filter = [{ dateTime: '2021-08-16 19:00:00', count: 1 }, { dateTime: '2021-08-17 05:00:00', count: 1 }],
    unwanted = new Set(filter.map(({ dateTime }) => dateTime)),
    result = array.filter(({ dateTime }) => !unwanted.has(dateTime));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
const newArr = [];

const brrDateTimes = brr.map((el) => el.dateTime);

arr.forEach((el) => {
  if (brrDateTimes.indexOf(el.dateTime) == -1) 
    newArr.push(el)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
time=brr.map(x=>x.dateTime);
arr.map(x=>!time.includes(x.dateTime))
```

Answer (score 1):

Array.filter operates on an entire array. You don't need to call it inside a loop. Furthermore, when comparing objects for sameness, you need to compare their scalar values. Objects with identical values are still not identical, in Javascript.

```js
const arr = [
    { dateTime: '2021-08-14 02:00:00', count: 1 },
    { dateTime: '2021-08-15 04:00:00', count: 1 },
    { dateTime: '2021-08-16 10:00:00', count: 1 },
    { dateTime: '2021-08-16 19:00:00', count: 1 },
    { dateTime: '2021-08-17 05:00:00', count: 1 }
];

const brr = [
    { dateTime: '2021-08-16 19:00:00', count: 1 },
    { dateTime: '2021-08-17 05:00:00', count: 1 }
];

const diff = arr.filter(a => {
    return !brr.some(b => {
      return a.dateTime === b.dateTime && a.count === b.count;
    });
});

console.log(diff);
```